# Collision Detection Error

Tags: java

I am currently working on a relatively simple platform game that has an odd bug.  You start the game by falling onto the ground (you spawn a few blocks above the ground), but when you land your feet get stuck INSIDE the world and you can't move until you jump.  Here's what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0fip.png

The player's feet are a few pixels below the ground level.  However, this problem only occurs in 3 places throughout the map and only in those 3 select places.  I'm assuming that the problem lies within my collision detection code but I'm not entirely sure, as I don't get an error when it happens.

```
public boolean isCollidingWithBlock(Point pt1, Point pt2) { 
//Checks x  
    for(int x = (int) (this.x / Tile.tileSize); x < (int) (this.x / Tile.tileSize + 4); x++) {
//Checks y
        for(int y = (int) (this.y / Tile.tileSize); y < (int) (this.y / Tile.tileSize + 4); y++) {
            if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < Component.dungeon.block.length && y < Component.dungeon.block[0].length) {
//If the block is not air
                if(Component.dungeon.block[x][y].id != Tile.air) {
                    //If the player is in contact with point one or two on the block 
                    if(Component.dungeon.block[x][y].contains(pt1) || Component.dungeon.block[x][y].contains(pt2)) {
//Checks for specific blocks 
                        if(Component.dungeon.block[x][y].id == Tile.portalBlock) {
                            Component.isLevelDone = true;
                        } 
                        if(Component.dungeon.block[x][y].id == Tile.spike) {
                            Health.health -= 1;
                            Component.isJumping = true;

                            if(Health.health == 0) {
                                Component.isDead = true;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

What I'm asking is how I would fix the problem.  I've looked over my code for quite a while and I'm not sure what's wrong with it.  Also, if there's a more efficient way to do my collision checking then please let me know!

I hope that is enough information, if it's not just tell me what you need and I'll be sure to add it.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you used a debugger or added SOP statements to view the values of the variables in the situations you described? This is where I suggest that you start. Learning how to debug code is just as important of a skill as learning how to write it in the first place.

Comment: Possibly a candidate for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is a SOP statement?

Comment: It would help us (and you) if you commented each line of code with what it does (i.e. //checking if touching block side //checks if touching block top etc)

Comment: @Connor -- SOP = "System.out.println"

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably isn't your collision check, but your logic of what to do on collision.  Your character is falling into the block which once in there is always colliding with the block.  So it won't be able to jump (since you check for collision when jumping I guess).  When you check for collision you have to make sure your character doesn't fall into the block by pre-checking and adjusting.

```
if (will collide) {
    put beside block
}
```

You're probably doing something like

```
if (colliding) {
    stop moving
}
```

When putting beside though, you have to check which way you're moving and that you don't move into blocks.